# Configuring navbar for iPhone 8 display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On iPhone 8 the navbar/stripe with the modes and results on a JavaScript game I built does not display all the items on one line and instead causes the last mode (hard) to drop to a second line.  I've tried multiple resizing and flexbox options but just can't seem to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button class="mode">Easy</button>
    <button class="mode selected" class="selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#stripe {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#message {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #container {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  #colorDisplay {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution with flex.

```css
#stripe {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    
    background-color: white;
}

#message {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button class="mode">Easy</button>
    <button class="mode selected" class="selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```